# What SSL VPN client do you recommend for the mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, vpn, ssl

I am currently using FortiClient. It would be nice to use the native MacOS VPN client (in the Settings) but I don't think it supports **SSL** VPN. I googled but did not find anything. Does anyone have a SSL VPN mac client to recommend? It has to support **SSL VPN**.

Comment: How can a VPN not be SSL? What specifically are your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

At our company we use [TunnelBlick](https://tunnelblick.net/index.html), free, customisable and very stable.
It support SSL VPN without any problem.